# How to navigate to another page when faceId identified?

Tags: ios, swift, face-id

when click button I added face id recognition and `if true`, need to navigate another page. But not working. application crashed. After few minutes navigate to the next page and back button not working.

```
 @IBAction func myProfile(_ sender: Any) {
    //    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MyProfile", sender: nil)
        let context:LAContext = LAContext()

        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil){
            context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Need to access with your finger print", reply: {(wasCorrect, error) in
                if wasCorrect{
                    print("correct")
                  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MyProfile", sender: nil)
                }else{
                print("incorrect")
                }
                })
        }else{
            print("finger print doesn't support touch id")
        }
    }
```

**Error message is:**

> [Animation] +[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:] being called from a
>   background thread. Performing any operation from a background thread
>   on UIView or a subclass is not supported and may result in unexpected
>   and insidious behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback of `evaluatePolicy` runs in a background queue so do

```
DisptachQueue.main.async {
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MyProfile", sender: nil)
}
```